# Liferay: LDAP Authentication not working

Tags: active-directory, ldap, liferay, liferay-6

LDAP Authentication has been enabled.
Test LDAP Connection returns successful.
Test LDAP Users returns with a list of users.
Test LDAP Groups is successful as well.

I sign out of Test@Liferay.com and try logging in as on of the users returned from "Test LDAP Users."
Authentication fails.

Liferay throws authentication fails very quickly as if it did not even check against Active Directory.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liferay does not connect to LDAP to do authentication. It imports LDAP entities (user/groups) into it's own db. Only after import you can authenticate with user from LDAP (Liferay's copy of user).

How did you setup LDAP import setting? On startup? Periodically?

UPDATE:

- Do you have errors in logs regarding ldap import?
- Which version of Liferay do you use?
- Do you have export to ldap enabled? (that never worked for me, meaning import failed because of export)

Comment: It's complicated. I've tried many different configurations. Even when I tell Liferay to do the import on startup, it still does not. The LDAP settings all return successful, but no import.

Comment: Do you have export to ldap enabled? (that never worked for me, meaning import failed because of export)  This one done the trick for me .Thank you @Martin Gamulin

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered with this problem before. I solved it now.

Do you enable the Export of LDAP. How you are doing the ldap configuration if you are using control panel-> Portal Setting then
You can check the search Filter of User portion and set objectClass=inetOrgPerson

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way to start troubleshooting these things is to get a network trace with something like WireShark and see what calls are being made as well as the corresponding replies.